# How to play a YouTube video in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, youtube-api

I want to play a YouTube video in my WPF application. I am using Google API and successfully get information about video but i don`t understand how to play a video. Here is my code which is i used for retrieve information.

```
  YouTubeRequestSettings setting = new YouTubeRequestSettings("MyAPP", "ID");
  YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(setting);
  YouTubeQuery myQuery = new YouTubeQuery(YouTubeQuery.MostPopular);
  myQuery.OrderBy = "viewCount";
  Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(myQuery);
  foreach (Video item in videoFeed.Entries)
       {
          listBox1.Items.Add(item.Title);
       }
```

thank`s

Comment: You have to write the code to take the information from the Video, and play the video, this requires knowlege of of the video format itself

Comment: You'll have to use a WebBrowser control - Here's an example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/YouViewer.aspx

Comment: Are you looking to play the video within a sort of widget which plays an online video OR to download the video, then play the local version?

Comment: Yea i want to play an Online video.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to use a WebBrowser control - Here's an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27121/Stream-YouTube-Videos-in-WPF

Cut and past of what Mike posted as comment :)