# UWP play a YouTube video

Tags: c#, youtube, uwp, video-streaming, youtube-data-api

I am trying to find a resource that would explain how to retrieve a YouTube video URL to play in an external player. Of course, I have taken a look at the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/youtube/v3), but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

However, I know it is possible, given that there exist YouTube client applications that are able to stream video (MetroTube is one example).

I saw the related post ([How to play a YouTube video in WPF using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313991/how-to-play-a-youtube-video-in-wpf-using-c-sharp)), but it was posted a long time ago. I would like to avoid having to use a WebBrowser control (or WebView in UWP).

Can someone suggest an approach or point to a resource that allows this?

Comment: You can use MediaElement to play

Comment: You can use WebView to play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used `MyToolKit.Extended` in the past to integrate `Youtube` Videos in one of my App.

Install Nuget Package from [Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MyToolkit.Extended/2.5.16)

Once done, you need to call this method

```
internal async Task<Uri> GetYoutubeUri(string VideoID)  
{  
    YouTubeUri uri = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(VideoID, YouTubeQuality.Quality1080P);  
    return uri.Uri;  
}
```

Make sure you are passing only `VideoID`. i.e, If your URL is

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UO-8CMdeSHA
```

you need to pass only `UO-8CMdeSHA`.

Once done, you will receive the actual Media Uri. You can now set this as a source to MediaPlayer. Something like below.

```
Uri _videoUri = await GetYoutubeUri("UO-8CMdeSHA");  
if (_videoUri != null)  
{  
    player.Source = _videoUri;  
    player.Play();  
}
```

To ensure you see basic Play/Pause button and few others, Use Below in your XAML.

```
MediaElement x:Name="player" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" />
```

And you should be able to play `YouTube` Videos.

Good Luck.

Comment: https://github.com/RicoSuter/MyToolkit/issues/103 seems to be outdated and not working anymore :( Alternative code example needed :)